# how to create a reactive question option form in angular 6 (data is coming from a service )

Tags: angular6

I am getting these data from a service .

I want to create a reactive question option form as per the data coming. In form I need to create question and options to select.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.data.getQuestionList().subscribe(
      data => this.questions$ = data

);
```

from this function I am getting these json data

```
[{"question_id":"1","questions":"where do you live ?","options":[{"option_id":"1","options_name":"Village"},{"option_id":"2","options_name":"City"}]},{"question_id":"2","questions":"what is your qualification ?","options":[{"option_id":"3","options_name":"Graduate"},{"option_id":"4","options_name":"Masters"}]}]
```

I need to create a dynamic form based on that json data. suppose i want to create a form, then i will write this thing in ts file.
ngOnInit() {

```
 this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['', Validators.required],
        lastName: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
    });
```

}
But for dynamic names, how to create. Lets say for question 1 there will be 3 option, and for question 2 there will be 3 options. The option field name should be on questions ID ,e.g for question 1 option1[ ], for question 2 option name will be option2[ ]

Answer (score 0):

Try following code will work

you can refer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wamyab-oujepa

component.ts

```
let questions = [{"question_id":"1","questions":"where do you live ?","options":[{"option_id":"1","options_name":"Village"},{"option_id":"2","options_name":"City"}]},{"question_id":"2","questions":"what is your qualification ?","options":[{"option_id":"3","options_name":"Graduate"},{"option_id":"4","options_name":"Masters"}]}]
```

component.html

```
<div >
  <ng-container *ngFor="let question of questions">
      <p>{{question.questions}}</p>
      <select>
        <option></option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of question.options">{{option.options_name}}</option>
      </select>

    </ng-container>
 </div>
```

Comment: I need to create a dynamic form based on that json data. suppose i want to create a form, then i will write this thing in ts file.
ngOnInit() {

     this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            firstName: ['', Validators.required],
            lastName: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
        });
  }